# Node.js REST url with Buffer id type

Tags: node.js, rest, base64, strongloop

in the REST path :  /products/{id}

how do you pass a binary id (of type Buffer).

```
binary : ÂµÃ¿Ã³Ã±â¹zMÂ â
hex : C2B5C3BFC3B3C3B1E280B97A4DC2A0E2
base64 : NEM3RDY0QzJBOUM0QjFDMzhGNDMwQUMzODc0QUNCOUQ=
```

None of the above work.

The rest api was generated with Strongloop.

Comment: Hey, have you made any progress on this question? Am having a similar issue.

Comment: I think I ended up using an integer id somehow.

Comment: When I access the binary value via my API I get something like the following object. `surveyId: {
    data: [12, 215, 191, 155, 118, 8, 64, 184, 140, 252, 91, 117, 104, 89, 96, 213]
    type: 'Buffer
}` ever seen anything like that or how to convert it to an id?

Comment: This seems to be the current state of affairs : https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/4161